# Enumeration problem redefining `enumerate` enivironment

Tags: enumerate

I would like to redefine the `enumerate` environment with an optional argument. Basically I want to redefine `\theenumi` so that each time I label an item and call it with `\ref` I get the real label printed, and not just the (arabic) value of counter `enumi`.

I tried with the code below, and it works except for the fact it always adds an extra point (`.`) to each label. When I call it with `\ref` it prints the correct label though.

Here is a MWE of what I tried:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%%
%%
\let\oldenumerate\enumerate
\let\endoldenumerate\endenumerate
\renewenvironment{enumerate}[1][\arabic{enumi}.]% Defaults to 1. 2. 3. ...
{%
    \bgroup\renewcommand\theenumi{#1}%
    \oldenumerate%
}%
{%
    \endoldenumerate\egroup%
}%
\begin{document}
First list with default enumeration
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}
Second list with custom enumeration
\begin{enumerate}[(\emph{\roman{enumi}})]
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}
Labels have an extra dot in the lists, but references \ref{a} and \ref{b} are printed correctly.
\end{document}
```

and this is the output of the above code:

[image: Output of the above MWE]

How should I redefine `enumerate` in order to avoid the extra dot in the lists?

Comment: You have loaded `\usepackage{enumerate}` which _already_ gives enumerate an optional argument with a different meaning, which complicates things, You would probably be better not to load that, or if you are loading that just use `\begin{enumerate}[(i)]` which probably does the right thing.

Comment: Alternatively, use the `enumitem` package instead, which allows you to specify the label explicitly: `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\emph{\roman*})]` along with any formatting.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much, now I get why the error occurs. `\begin{enumerate}[(i)]` works well, but when I `\ref` the first item it gives `1` instead of `(i)`

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you very much, your solution works perfectly! Why don't you post your comment as an answer so that I can close the question?

Comment: @AndreasT In case you're willing to implement Alan's suggestion, you may also specify how your enumerated list entries will be referred to! For instance, `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\emph{\roman*}), ref=(\roman*)]` would do the job.

Comment: @KannappanSampath Great hint, thanks! I am going to read `enumitem`'s documentation right away

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than reinventing the wheel, it's much easier to use the `enumitem` package for this sort of thing.  For this particular example I've added a negative kern so that the parentheses are spaced nicely with the italic numeral.  As Kannappan Sampath points out, you can specify the format of the references separately as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
Second list with custom enumeration
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\kern-.5pt\emph{\roman*}),ref=(\roman*)]
\item First item \label{a}
\item Second item \label{b}
\end{enumerate}
Labels have an extra dot in the lists, but references \ref{a} and \ref{b} are printed correctly.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%%% Set the default: number followed by a period
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*.}

\begin{document}
First list with default enumeration
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item\label{a} Second item
\end{enumerate}
Second list with custom enumeration
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\emph{\roman*})]
\item First item
\item\label{b} Second item
\end{enumerate}
Labels have an extra dot in the lists, and references
\ref{a} and \ref{b} are printed correctly.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @egreg, your solution works very well. Alan Munn commented first so I accepted his answer.